# How to edit a input value on click with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, click

I am trying to build a mind mapping tool with JQuery and I am struggling with the editing of a div content.

I wrote a function allowing me to add text to a (mind-container) div. It works well.
However it does not let me edit the text once it is set.

Here is a live example: https://jsfiddle.net/TiOw87/c9wwe81d/5/

*Here is my JQuery function:*

```
$('.mind-container').click(function(){
    $('input').addClass('active');
    $('input').parent().find('input').focus();
    $('input').keyup(function(event){
        if(event.keyCode == 13){
            var string = $(this).val();
            $(this).removeClass('active');
                if ($(this).has("p"))
            {
                $(this).parent().html("<p>"+ string +"</p>")
            }
            else
            {
                $(this).parent().append("<p>"+ string +"</p>")
            }
        }   
    })
});
```

*And my HTML:*

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<body>

  <div id='board'>
    <div class='mind-container' id='mind-master'>
      <input type="text">
    </div>

  </div>

</body>
```

I would like to be able to click on the div and be able to edit the value of the input text already in it.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Why don't you just use `contenteditable` attribute on your div? read about here http://html5demos.com/contenteditable and here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is your usage of `has()`.  http://api.jquery.com/has/  `has()` reduces the matched set of elements, it does not return a boolean.  And since a jQuery object is always truthy, the logic is executing the first conditional, using `html()` to replace the entire contents of the div with the p string.  As a side effect, your input box is no longer there to be interacted with.

Changing the conditional to be `has(...).length` will fix the always truthy issue, however the potential issue of removing the input box by doing `html()` still exists.

Side note, you have another issue with doing a nested binding within the keyup handler, which will result in multiple bindings.  You should fix this too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I naively thought that has would return a boolean. Adding .length resolved my conditional issue.
I also added a $('p',this) in the first line of my fuction so the previous inputs are erased before the edit is saved.
However I do have another problem which is the number of time the div is clicked.
For instance, the first time you give the value "1" and displays properly. You click again, replace "1" by "Hello" and then "HelloHello" is displayed. Like because you clicked the first time to input 1 and a second time to edit, it runs the function twice

Comment: Correct, because of the nested binding that I mention in the last part.  You should not be repeatedly binding an event handler to a single element.